# Return multi widgets inside MaterialApp builder property

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using responsive_framework & bot_toast, and to initialize them, I need to use the builder property inside the MaterialApp.

> responsive_framework

```
builder: (context, widget) {
    return ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
      BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(context, widget),
      maxWidth: 1200,
      minWidth: 450,
      defaultScale: true,
      breakpoints: [
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(480, name: MOBILE),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: DESKTOP),
      ],
      background: Container(
        color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      ),
    );
  },
```

> bot_toast

```
MaterialApp(
  title: 'BotToast Demo',
  builder: BotToastInit(), //1. call BotToastInit
  navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()], //2. registered route observer
  home: XxxxPage(),
```

)

My question here, how can I configure them, even though both of these packages use the builder property?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**I found the solution**

```
@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
final botToastBuilder = BotToastInit();
return MaterialApp(    
  builder: (context, child) {
    child = ResponsiveWrapper.builder(
      BouncingScrollWrapper.builder(context, child),
      maxWidth: 1200,
      minWidth: 450,
      defaultScale: true,
      breakpoints: [
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(480, name: MOBILE),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(800, name: TABLET),
        ResponsiveBreakpoint.autoScale(1000, name: DESKTOP),
      ],
      background: Container(
        color: Color(0xFFF5F5F5),
      ),
    );

    child = botToastBuilder(context, child);
    return child;
  },
  navigatorObservers: [BotToastNavigatorObserver()],
 
);
}
```

Thanks to https://github.com/MMMzq/bot_toast/issues/55